# Missing val_loss and val_accuracy after overriding the fit function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-tuner

Following [Keras Tuner's documentation](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/) for implementing a custom objective function, the fit function of my model's class is as below:

```
class HyperAE(kt.HyperModel):
  def build(self, hp):
      ...
  
  def fit(self, hp, model, x, y, validation_data, **kwargs):
      model.fit(x, y, **kwargs)
      x_val, y_val = validation_data
      y_pred = model.predict(x_val)
      return {
        "metric_1": -np.mean(np.abs(y_pred - y_val)),
        "metric_2": np.mean(np.square(y_pred - y_val)),
      }
```

When running the tuner with this model, I can't see `val_loss` and other validation metrics printed as before. How can I make them to get printed again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because `validation_data` is not passed to the actual `model.fit` function call. The problem can be fixed as below:

```
class HyperAE(kt.HyperModel):
  def build(self, hp):
      ...
  
  def fit(self, hp, model, x, y, validation_data, **kwargs):
      model.fit(x=x, y=y, validation_data=validation_data, **kwargs)
      x_val, y_val = validation_data
      y_pred = model.predict(x_val)
      return {
        "metric_1": -np.mean(np.abs(y_pred - y_val)),
        "metric_2": np.mean(np.square(y_pred - y_val)),
      }
```